# C dynamic memory allocation for table of structs

Tags: c, memory-management

Hi here is my code. I want to dynamincly change no of elemnts in table with structs __state:

```
typedef struct __state{
    long int timestamp;
    int val;
    int prev_value;
}*state_p, state_t;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int zm;
    int previous_state = 0;
    int state = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    state_p st;
    //here i want to have 20 structs st.
    st = (state_p) malloc(sizeof(state_t) * 20);
    while(1){
        previous_state = state;
        scanf("%d", &state);
        printf("%d, %d\n", state, previous_state);
        if (previous_state != state){
            printf("state changed %d %d\n", previous_state, state);
            // here i got compile error:
               main.c: In function ‘main’:
               main.c:30: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘save_state’
               main.c:34: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’
               main.c:34: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’

            save_state(st[i],previous_state, state);
        }
        i++;
    }
return 0;
}
```

I suppose i have to change that `st[i]` to smth like `st+ptr` ? where pointer is incermeting in each loop iteration ? Or am I wrong ? When i change code: initialization into `state_p st[20]` and in each loop iteration i put `st[i] = (state_p)malloc(sizeof(state_t))` everything works fine, but i want to dynammicly change number of elemets in that table.

Thx in advance for any help

Comment: What's the function prototype for save_state()?

Comment: Though it's not related to your question, you should realize that the name `__state` is reserved for the implementation, so you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Here it is:
(sorry i dont know where how to put 'code tag' here)
void save_state(state_p st, int previous_state, int state){
    st->timestamp = 0;
    st->prev_value = previous_state;
    st->val = state;
}

Comment: Edit your question and put the method definition there.  Remember to do proper code escaping.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show the prototype for `save_state`.  I'm assuming the first parameter should be a *pointer* to a state.  If that's the case, then you need:

```
save_state(st + i, previous_state, state);
```

or

```
save_state(&(st[i]), previous_state, state);
```